# $\prod_{I=0}^{24} \frac{n- i - 1}{n - i}$ have closed form?

Tags: closed-form, products

I am evaluating the closed form of

$\prod_{I=0}^{24} \frac{n- i - 1}{n - i}$ where $n > 25 \in N$

I can see that I cam get closed form of this if I do multiplication 25 times. Yet, I would like to know whether it is possible to get the form by other ways.

Comment: It often helps to write out the first few terms of a sum explicitly. Had you done that in this case, the answer would have been obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Observe
\begin{align}
\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-2}{n-1}\cdots \frac{n-24}{n-23}\frac{n-25}{n-24} = \frac{n-25}{n} 
\end{align}

or

\begin{align}
\prod^{24}_{i=0} \frac{n-i-1}{n-i} =&\ \exp\left(\sum^{24}_{i=0}\left[\log(n-i-1)-\log(n-i) \right] \right)\\
=&\ \exp\left(\log(n-25)-\log(n) \right)  = \frac{n-25}{n}
\end{align}
by Telescoping sum.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{i=0}^{24}{n-i-1\over n-i}
&=\left(n-1\over n \right)\left(n-2\over n-1 \right)\left(n-3\over n-2 \right)\cdots\left(n-24\over n-23 \right)\left(n-25\over n-24 \right)\\
&={1\over n}\left(n-1\over n-1 \right)\left(n-2\over n-2 \right)\cdots\left(n-24\over n-24 \right)(n-25)\\
&={n-25\over n}\\
&=1-{25\over n}
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is essentially the same as Jacky Chong's answer, just with an extra step to make the cancellations obvious (and a final step that might be considered a simplification).